# How to Get Byte Array Between Two Addresses

Tags: c#, memory

I want to read the array of bytes in between two address using memory.dll library for c#.

Im new to memory.dll library and dont have enough knowledge of parsing the data from memory.dll

so basically i want string which between twwo address

So i want to get string in array of bytes in between those text using memory.dll in c#

```
    static private readonly Mem mem = new MemoryX();
    static private bool IsProcOpen;
    static private int ProcessID;
    ProcessID = mem.GetProcIdFromName("Calimba");
        
        if (ProcessID != 0)
        {
            IsProcOpen = mem.OpenProcess(ProcessID);
            
            Console.WriteLine("Process ID : " + ProcessID + " ");
            IEnumerable<long> AoBScanResults = await mem.AoBScan("4F 4D 44 55 4E 47 45 4F 4E 40 ?? ?? ??", true, true, true);
            IEnumerable<long> AoBScanResults2 = await mem.AoBScan("24 ?? 90 ?? 24 48 88 ?? ??", true, true, true);



            long SingleAoBScanResult = AoBScanResults.FirstOrDefault();
            long SingleAoBScanResult2 = AoBScanResults2.FirstOrDefault();


            // pop up message box that shows our first result
            Console.WriteLine("Our First Found Address from " + SingleAoBScanResult);
            Console.WriteLine("Our First Found Address to " + SingleAoBScanResult2);
```

so i want to get array of bytes and save in text file by using middle of the two addresses which i get in

```
long SingleAoBScanResult = AoBScanResults.FirstOrDefault();
long SingleAoBScanResult2 = AoBScanResults2.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What is `Mem` ?

Comment: updated the code sir, its memory.dll

Comment: What <type> is `Mem` and what is memory.dll. Are you talking about `System.Memory.dll` or `System.Runtime.dll` which contains `Memory<T>`, or https://www.processlibrary.com/en/directory/files/memory/1052/ ?? Please give a full specification of the types used.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Looking at the signatures, I believe it's [this library](https://github.com/erfg12/memory.dll).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes its https://github.com/erfg12/memory.dll im sorry for my bad english but i already clerify that on the start of the topic. Its c# memory.dll library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/erfg12/memory.dll/blob/2d8ad13631b755106a60c3e42f242ce5db78270d/Memory/Methods/Read.cs#L32) for the library, it should be as simple as:

```
long start = AoBScanResults.FirstOrDefault();
long end = AoBScanResults2.FirstOrDefault();

//NOTE: Please do some sanity checking to make sure start is less than end.
long length = end - start;

byte[] result = mem.ReadBytes(start.ToString("x"), length);
```

Edit: Digging further, it seems the string containing the start address is [parsed as base 16](https://github.com/erfg12/memory.dll/blob/2d8ad13631b755106a60c3e42f242ce5db78270d/Memory/memory.cs#L539). Modified the above to `ToString("x")` which will convert the number to hexadecimal.

Comment: I tried that but always get null array

Comment: @JayComputers  Seems like we may need the address string formatted as hex. I've added an edit above. Give that a shot.